# Set a dynamic variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, dynamic

I am trying to make my code look a little prettier, which is a function that has maybe 16 arguments and does a lot of repeated code with these arguments.

Here's some sample code to demonstrate my problem:

```
function foo(varList, a, b, c, d, e, f, ...) {
  varList.map(bar => {
    console.log('Result: ' + bar);
  }
}

const vars = ['b', 'd', 'f'];
foo(vars, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Results in

```
b, d, f
```

I am actually trying to access the data in those variable names instead, so it should print:

```
1, 3, 5
```

Is there a way to dynamically work with variables like this?

Comment: Why not create an object that maps these letters to these numbers, e.g. `const obj = {'b': 1, 'd': 3, 'f': 5}` then when you want to print the corresponding number do: `obj['b']` or `obj.b`

Comment: That's actually exactly what I ended up doing.  Post as answer and will mark.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @alfasin answered, just use the power of [JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). An object consists of key-value pairs, where each `key` is a string and the corresponding `value` can be an arbitrary JavaScript object.

For your example code, you can simply write:

```
const vars = {'b': 1, 'd': 3, 'f': 5};
```

To access the value of a certain object key, either write `vars.b` or `vars['b']` to access the value of `b` (which is `1`) for example.